# Yii: Add a JavaScript to the header

Tags: php, yii

I need `<script>` in header to define a JavaScript variable (`var dates={...};`) which is to be used from a `.js` script.

It should be preferably in header and not inside `jQuery(function($){...})` not to hide the variable from using it by my `.js` script.

Can it be done in any other way than modifying the layout?

Comment: How about [`Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript($script_source, CClientScript::POS_HEAD)`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#registerScript-detail) in the controller?

Comment: @DCoder: Your code produces a script wrapped into jQuery(function($){...}) what is unsatisfactory for me.

Comment: You can still export a symbol into the global scope... `$(function() { window.dates = ... ; })` (though you might want to think about a more unique name for it).

Comment: @DCoder's example is wrong in that it's missing the first argument (script id). The correct example is `Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript($scriptId, $scriptSource, CClientScript::POS_HEAD)` and for me at least, on Yii 1.1.13, it will not be wrapped inside `jQuery()`. That would happen on `CClientScript::POS_READY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually do this:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('my vars','
    var myFirstVar="something";
    var myUrl="' . CController::createUrl("controller/action") . '";
    ,CClientScript::POS_HEAD);
```